# Angularjs: Separate elements for 'editable' mode and 'readonly' mode?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have an Angular app with a lot of form elements. In 'edit' mode, the user is able to edit the input items, change options, mark checkboxes, etc. In 'read' mode, the should only be able to read this values. Only admins will be able to edit anything on the page, other people will only be able to read the content.

What I would like to do is to just have the script use plain `span` or `div` elements in read only mode in order to reduce the number of watchers overall. Implementation wise, I always end up having to define two separate html 'blocks' like shown below.

**exampleInput.tpl.html**

Note: I use `ng-if` here because I want to remove the input element from the DOM in read-only mode in order to reduce the number of watchers.

```
    <!-- editable mode. -->
    <input 
      ng-if="!$ctrl.isReadOnly()"
      ng-model="$ctrl.value" 
      value="$ctrl.value"
    />
    <!-- read only -->
    <span 
      ng-if="$ctrl.isReadOnly()"
      ng-bind="$ctrl.value">
    </span>
```

**exampleInput.comp.js**

```
    // The example-input component
    (function(){
      "use strict";
      angular
        .module("exampleInput", ["ngSanitize", "userSettings"])
        .component("exampleInput", {
          templateUrl: "exampleInput.tpl.html",
          bindings: {
            value: "="
          },
          transclude: true,
          controller: ["$scope", "userSettings", function($scope, userSettings){
              var ctrl = this;
              ctrl.isReadOnly = userSettings.isReadOnly;
            }
          ]
        });
    }());
```

**Application**:

```
    <qa-input value="value.foobar">
    </qa-input>
```

---

**My Question**:

Is there a better way to do it? I know I can just have a single input element and use css to control the styling in 'disabled' mode but that doesn't remove the watchers which is my main reason for doing things this way. I'm fairly new to Angular so any advice is appreciated.

I am using Angular 1.5.x.

Comment: Can you use [something like this](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#edit-disabled) ? It already has `enable / disable` and lots of other functionalities. I use it for one of my applications and it is a huge time saver.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea this even existed! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it per element, you could create a template for editing and one for reading and then swap them out by changing the variable passed to an `ng-include` based on whether you are in edit-mode or not.

Comment: This sounds like a really excellent idea. Do you know if there are any performance impacts to doing it this way (assuming all my template files are stored in the same directory)?

Comment: None that I know of. In fact, you should be able to use the one-time binding syntax {{ :: variable }} everywhere in the read only template to make it really lightweight.

Comment: If you're worried about the performance of loading the templates themselves, it's usually negligible. However, you could also preload them by injecting $templateCache.

Comment: Also `<ng-template>` can be used to group set of adjacent controls that depend on the same `ngIf` condition to make it more clear